# PHP code returning itself rather than executing - wasn't occuring before?

Tags: php, html

[Example of code returning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Atx.png)

Everytime I execute my php on the webpage, it returns the code within the solution rather than running the php. It wasn't doing this before, and I've entered the tags correctly and named the files as told. I know a few of the same issues have been raised, but I couldn't put a finger on why mine was doing the same.

Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page duplicate of this problem.

Comment: Yes I saw but everything seemed fine compared. Any help?

Comment: and you are sure php is installed?

Comment: currently on a university machine, so I'm sure it is installed.

Comment: ...used as `http://localhost` (or hosted) or as `Drive:/file:///`? big difference here @Charliejb

Comment: thank you just realised from the other forum, so stupid of me!!!!